# Rails 4 Couldn't find file 'angular-rails-templates'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, angular-template

I'm following this tutorial: https://thinkster.io/angulartutorial/angular-rails/ and everything went well till the part where I had to arrange my angular code with folders in the rails assets pipeline javascripts and use the gem 'angular-rails-template' (https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates) to reach them.

I've installed the gem through the Gemfile and I'm getting a "couldn't find file 'angular-rails-templates'" error even though I've required the file in the application.js:

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require_tree .
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apperantly I was sure that I restarted the server, which I didn't. If anyone encouter this problem try the old fashioned solution to fix it.

Comment: +1, forgot to restart too... Working with rails is so awsome that you easily get used to not restarting the server every second